# How do you reload a variable shown in HTML when it changes value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, reload

My HTML shows a variable inside of a script tag, and I want to reload only that variable.

```
<script class="scriptClass">document.write(myObject.myProperty);</script>
<button>Go</button>
```

When a function runs that changes the value of myObject.myProperty, it needs to be updated in the HTML. JavaScript is something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    myProperty:"Initial"
};
function myPropertyChange(){
    myObject.myProperty = "somethingDifferent";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        myPropertyChange();
        $("script.scriptClass").empty();
        $("script.scriptClass").html("document.write(myObject.myProperty);");
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, and I've tried a number a variations on this with .replaceWith and .replace. I also tried adding location.reload(true);, but I think that just resets the whole thing.

Comment: You cannot reload a script. Check out my answer. See if that suits you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading a `<script>` tag, can you assign it to a `<div>`. Something like this:

```js
myObject = {};
myObject.myProperty = "Initial";
function myPropertyChange(){
  myObject.myProperty = "somethingDifferent";
  $("#theProperty").text(myObject.myProperty);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theProperty").text(myObject.myProperty);
  $("button").click(function(){
    myPropertyChange();
    $("script.scriptClass").empty();
    $("script.scriptClass").html("document.write(myObject.myProperty);");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="theProperty"></span>
<button>Go</button>
```